# Right click "Icon Tasks"

Tags: java, jframe, jump-list

How do i create "icon tasks". I would like to replicate how some programs function (such as stickynotes/spotify) when you right click on their icons. I apologize I cannot include an image for I do not have enough reputation; however, (I am using Windows 8.1) if you right click on Chrome's Icon your "Most visited" and its "Tasks" pop up. Does anyone know how to replicate this? I cannot find anything, I must be asking the wrong questions. I found [this](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.sf.squirrel-sql.thirdpary-non-maven/org-netbeans-modules-editor-lib/4.0/org/netbeans/editor/JumpList.java#1), but I could not get it to work.

Comment: It might not be possible in Java - this is an OS-specific feature.

Comment: You can't do this from Java itself, you will need some kind of native integration to support it.  I stumbled across [this (paid) library](http://www.strixcode.com/j7goodies/) some time ago, but never had a chance to really look at it (nor really wanted to pay for it)